# Can a Java interface in another package be refactored from my code?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, interface, package

I'm using an (open-source) API in my Java project and referencing interfaces from it. One interface (`Foo`) is used extensively both in the API and in projects that use it. For my project, I'd like to use an interface which only exposes a subset of the methods that `Foo` does, such that `Foo` would inherit methods from my new interface (`Bar`). I don't want to change the interface of `Foo` at all; rather, I'd like to be able to write classes which implement `Bar`, and then manipulate those along with classes which implement `Foo` as if they are all `Bar`.

Since the API is in a different package, is there any way to accomplish this such that `Bar` is a superclass (interface) of all `Foo`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably going to need to use an [Aspect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) to make this happen.  It looks like [AspectJ](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj) has a [@DeclareParents](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/adk15notebook/ataspectj-itds.html) that might do what you want.

Comment: If I understand this correctly, this creates delegates on-the-fly which essentially act as adapters. Can I still write my `BarImpl` class as implementing `Bar` and only apply the `@DeclareParents` (or `@DeclareMixin`) to `Foo`? Some of the examples I saw seemed to avoid making `BarImpl` an actual implementation of `Bar`.

Comment: Hmm, not sure, haven't used Aspects for this purpose before.  What you say makes me doubt this is a home run solution.  Manual adapters might be a more reliable and maintainable way to go.

Answer (score 3):

> I'd like to be able to write classes which implement Bar, and then
>   manipulate those along with classes which implement Foo as if they are
>   all Bar.

You can create an abstract Bar that implements Foo.  You'll leave off the methods shared by the two and implement the methods that Bar does not share so they throw an exception like `UnsupportedOperationException`.

But you can't manipulate Foo as if it were Bar; it's the other way 'round.  You can't satisfy the Liskov Substitution Principle the way you're proposing.

Comment: I would argue that throwing `UnsupportedOperationException` from an implementation of `Foo` also doesn't satisfy LSP, and should generally be avoided. Though I understand there is precedent, and it can be the right choice in some circumstances.

Comment: Agreed, it's not satisfactory from the point of view of the user, but it's necessary for the sake of the compiler.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [Adapter Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) to accomplish this:

```
public class FooAdapter implements Bar {
   private Foo wrapped;
   public FooAdapter(Foo foo) {
      wrapped = foo;
   }
   public void op1() {
      foo.op1();
   }
   public string op2(int param) {
      return foo.op2(param);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because Java has nominal typing, such that `org.theirs.Foo` is in no way related to `org.yours.Foo`, even if they have the exact same method signatures, I don't think this is possible to do with inheritance in Java. Even with generics, AFAIK there is no way to say, "this method takes an instance of `Bar<T extends Foo OR Bar>`".

Instead, I think you want to use an [Adapter interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) for the library's `Foo`, with your own (i.e. a `FooAdapter`, having the exact same signatures as `Foo`) and have this extend `Bar`. The methods you want in `Bar` could then be extracted from `FooAdapter`. Unfortunately your code would have to be modified so that *everywhere* you previously referenced their `Foo`, you would instead reference either:

- `Bar` if the only methods called are those you would define in your interface
- `FooAdapter` if methods defined in `Foo` but NOT in `Bar` are called.

This method, although clean, and a good separation of concerns, can be painful and tedious to implement, I'm afraid.

An example of how this would work is shown in the following code snippets:

### 3rd Party Library

```
package org.theirs;
public interface Foo {
    void doSomething();
    void doSomethingExtra();
}
```

### Your code

```
package org.mine;
public interface Bar {
    void doSomething();
}

public class BarImpl implements Bar{
     public void doSomething( /* implementation */ );
}

public class FooAdapter implements Bar{
    private final Foo adapted;
    public FooAdapter(Foo adapted) {
         this.adapted = adapted;
    }
    public void doSomething() {
        adapted.doSomething(); // delegate to adapted instance
    }
}

public class UsingThoseBars {
    public void doSomethingWithAllThoseBars(Collection<Bar> bars) {
         // each entry in bars could either be a BarImpl or a FooAdapter    
    }
}
```

You can see from this example that the method `doSomethingExtra()` is not accessible from your code, since the interface `Bar` does not specify it.

### Other Suggestions

Note there may be useful tricks you could do with class rewriting, such as with AspectJ. I'm assuming you'd rather have the effect you desire at compile-time, in pure Java.

Another suggestion is to have an implementation of `Bar` which throws `UnsupportedOperationException` for the methods of `Foo` that you don't need. Although there is a precedent for this in major Java libraries (e.g. `UnmodifiableList` in the JDK) I would recommend against this practice in general. However, if the cost of replacing references to their `Foo` with your new `FooAdapter` is quite high, it may be a good trade off to use this strategy.